# How to remove a wallet from Android Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

I'm using [Bitcoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) for Android.  I recently backed up my wallet's keys and did a fresh install to a new device and restored my wallet there.  All great so far..

I'd now like to remove the fresh empty wallet that the app created for me when I did the install, but can't find a way to remove it from the application's address book.  Anyone know how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I think I misunderstood what this app is showing me.  A bitcoin wallet can (and often does) have multiple addresses (public+private keypairs).  What I was seeing in the app was not multiple wallets, but just multiple addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Web interface, you can archive addresses and then in the Archive view you can delete addresses.

Comment: I'm sorry, where is the web interface for this application?  It's an Android app..

Comment: There is no web interface.